# StringDateTime to Epoch/Unix conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have "Fri Dec 04 07:00:16 CST 2020" timestamp, need to convert it to Unix/Epoch time in python code
And how to convert reverse [Epoch time to above format]

Thanks,

Comment: Can you provide a output format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `time` and `datetime` module:

```
>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>> now = time.time()
>>> now
1607055249.4696143
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(now).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2020-12-04 01:14:09'
```

If you want to modify the format, you can take a look to the **strftime** documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).

Comment: Yes This helps me, btw how to do conversion from 'Fri Dec 04 07:00:16 CST 2020' to unix time, any tips pls

Comment: Sorry, just change the function `.strftime()` to `.timestamp()` like this: `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(a).timestamp()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use dateparser [dateparser](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/) . Here is the code

```
>>> import dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse('Fri Dec 04 07:00:16 CST 2020').strftime('%s')
'1607045416'
```

you have to install dateparser first
For reverse format you can do the same by passing argument to strftime.[strftime](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime)

Comment: Thanks, 

I hit with below issue,

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/arvinaya/PycharmProjects/study_assignments/TrainingTasks/dictTest.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(dateparser.parse('Fri Dec 04 07:00:16 CST 2020').strftime('%s'))
ValueError: Invalid format string